# How do I get the latest stable version of Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

How do I get the latest stable version of Angular JS?  The web site, https://code.angularjs.org/ shows that version 2.x is still listed as "alpha" and "beta" and some documentation online says that version 2.x is still in a testing phase.

But a friend told me to use the Package Manager Console with Visual studio to get the latest version of Angular JS.  But the exact command line command to make this happen seems elusive and not found easily online.

Please advise.

angular.io has a quick start link that points to a gethub that touts Angular 2, not Angular 4 https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html points to https://github.com/angular/quickstart

Comment: You probably want the 'new' angular(aka angular2, angularX), which is at version 4 already and has a new website: https://angular.io/

Comment: if you want the older version you are referring to is @ https://angularjs.org/

Comment: **Latest Stable Version:** `AngularJS v1.6.4 - (March 31, 2017)`. For more information see, [StackOverflow: AngularJS tag Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/angularjs/info).

Comment: Thanks for your hellp.  https://angular.io/ brought me to a gethub where I downloaded what I suppose id Angular 4

Comment: Riverside, angular.io has a quick start link that points to a gethub that touts Angular 2, not Angular 4 https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html points to https://github.com/angular/quickstart

Comment: That's because that was the first version of the 'new' angular. But they quickly went up to version 4(they skipped v. 3 to align versions). Quite some things have changed since v2 and when searching for tuts and other stuff you have to be very careful and make sure it's a recent one made for v4(There are especially many tuts around for v2 beta versions, but most of them simply do not work anymore).  I wouldn't suggest starting with v2, because many devs already switched to v4.

Comment: Also to address your concern about the quickstart repo a bit more: As can be seen in some commit messages(and the package.json) they updated the quickstart to work with v4.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize what I have written in comments:

- Newest version of angular is currently(14.5.2017) `4.1.2`
- Website at `angularjs.org` is the 'old' angular(pre version 2, also called angularjs). As of now they seem to be still releasing new versions(containing bug fixes and even new features).
- `angular.io` is the new website for angular(v2+)
- The [quickstart repo](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) for angular the OP mentioned in the comments seems to be updated regularly and the latest release has been updated to use angular 4
- When searching for tutorials and other stuff related to angular it's important to search for recent ones, because there are a lot of tutorials out there that were written using some early versions(even beta) versions of angular 2. These often don't work with newer versions